How can I support building two platforms with cmake and seperate solutions?
I am trying to make two Visual Studio solutions, one per platform, that that would contain a lib and exe per solution of that platform. However, when trying to do so, I run into the following issues

My current attempt is putting both "someexe-x64" and "someexe-tools" into the same solution ("Tools-Platform"). I want to have "someexe-tools" and "somelib-tools" only in this solution
If, for example, I wanted to introduce a third solution in the future, my current attempt would produce multiple projects of the same name (as a result of using "add_subdirectory", how could that be prevented?
I am currently using CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM based upon the suggestion of CMake: How to specify target platform? . Should this not be used twice per CMakeLists.txt? If not, what should be used differently or folder structure look like?

My folder structure is
CMakeLists.txt
    |--someexe
       |--CMakeLists.txt
    |--somelib
       |--CMakeLists.txt
    |--scripts
       |--tools
          |--CMakeLists.txt
       |--x64
          |--CMakeLists

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(GlobalProject)

#add_subdirectory(somelib)
#add_subdirectory(someexe)

add_subdirectory(scripts/tools)

someexe\CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

# -- setup x64 exe
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)

project(someexe-x64 CXX)

add_executable(someexe-x64 ../main.cpp)

# -- setup tools library
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM tools)

project(somelib-tools CXX)

add_executable(someexe-tools ../main.cpp)

somelib\CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

# -- setup x64 library
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)

project(somelib-x64 CXX)

add_library(somelib-x64 ../main.cpp)

# -- setup tools library
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM tools)

project(somelib-tools CXX)

add_library(somelib-tools ../main.cpp)

scripts\tools\CMakeLists.txt
# Specify the minimum version for CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Project's name
project(Tools-Platform)

# Add subdirectory that contains the other project
add_subdirectory(../../someexe ../../build2022/someexe)


Deleting a question and reposting it again with small changes is highly discouraged on Stack Overflow. Why do you do that?

In CMake you cannot have two targets which shares the same name. However, you may have different executable targets which creates a file with the same filename: add_executable(TestFlags64 ../main.cpp), set_target_properties(TestFlags64 PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME TestFlags). Still you cannot make a single CMake project targeting different platforms. Documentation explicitly tells, that variable CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM should NOT be set in the project code.

@Tsyvarev I deleted the question as the focus seemed to be on how can I put it into one solution, when I wanted the focus to not be on alternative solutions. Since it was already marked as a duplicate, I decided to try to resolve the confusion in the question

@Tsyvarev Would the ideal pattern then be to have the CMakeLists.txt be present for each exe\lib per platform and set the output name to which we would like for it to have? At that point, is the add_executable name only there for cmake's reference?

"... as the focus seemed to be on how can I put it into one solution, when I wanted the focus to not be on alternative solutions" - Sorry, I don't understand that. The code of your CMakeLists.txt, where you have two add_subdirectory calls, clearly tells that you are focused on having a single CMake project for both "platforms". Also, would you have different CMake projects, then your won't have a conflict for the target names.

@Tsyvarev I meant to write "I wanted the focus to be on an alternative solution". In a situation such as this, when I would now have a different example, while there are no proposed answers here, how would I then ask the updated question?

"while there are no proposed answers here, how would I then ask the updated question?" - Just edit the question to the desired form.

@Tsyvarev I have updated the question with an updated example as well

Just use single CMakeLists.txt and configure it separately for every platform you want. This is what CMake is intended for: define a content (libraries and executables) in a platform-independent way, and build that content for any target platform.
